# How to make a member function friend

Tags: c++, visual-c++, friend-function

I try to use the function fB a member function in class B to access the private member x in class A. fB is a friend function to class A. However, when I run the following code in vs 2015, there is an error that Member "A::x" is inaccessible to fB.

```
class A; 

class B
{
public:
    void fB(A& a); 
};

class A
{
    friend void B::fB(A& a);
private:
    int x = 0;
};

void B::fB(A& a) {
    ++a.x;//Error: Member "A::x" is inaccessible
}
```

Comment: see this https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/465sdshe.aspx

Comment: Works on gcc. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25c52d727d13972e

Comment: @Gernot1976 I tryed this code,using gcc or clang it works ,but when using VS2015,it doesn't....

Comment: Amazing，I changed to another computer,also using Vs2015 ,this code works.But on the first compute it still doesn't work

Comment: Rather than "build", try "rebuild all".